# Is it true: $\min_{y}E_Xg(X,y) \le \max_{x}E_Yg(x, Y)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

In my research I stack with this problem.

Let $X, Y$ are random values, and $g(x, y)$ some function (with values in $\mathbb{R}$). Is this inequality true?

$$\inf_{y_0}E_Xg(X, y_0)\le \sup_{x_0}E_Yg(x_0, Y)$$

Comment: I apologize, but I genuinely don't understand several things you've written. What does "$\xi(x,y)$ is a random value on the $X \times Y$" mean? Are $X$ and $Y$ random variables here? If so, what is the meaning of $X \times Y$? Do $X$ and $Y$ need to have any specific relationship to one another? It might help if you can give a concrete example to illustrate what you're saying.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery. Sorry, I edited the question

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent.  $ \inf E_X [g(X,y)] \le E[g(X,Y)] \le sup E_Y[g(x,Y)]$

Comment: @Boby, why the left (right) inquality is true?